# SparkR summarize function called within another function

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Say in `SparkR` I want to count the number of occurrences of different elements in a `DataFrame`, so I wrote a function:

```
count_spark <- function(df, col) {
  newCol <- paste0('N_', col)
  df %>%
    group_by(.[[col]]) %>%
    summarize(newCol = count(df[[col]]))
}
count_spark(df, 'EventType')
```

It's not what I expected because `newCol` is interpreted literally, so instead of having a new column called `N_EventType`, a new column called `newCol` is created.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `alias` like this:

```
count_spark <- function(df, col) {
  newCol <- paste0('N_', col)
  df %>%
    group_by(.[[col]]) %>%
    summarize(alias(count(df[[col]]), newCol))
}
```